# Exported activity does not require permission

Tags: java, android

So, I am going over tutorials to learn android and I have the bellow code which is giving me this warning in the title and the app will not run for some reason any help?

This is the code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.learn.tam.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.learn.tam.StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The part that is showing the error is the Second
        < activity

Answer (score 3):

You are advertising that any application on the device can start `com.example.learn.tam.StartingPoint`, and Lint is warning you that this is insecure.

Most likely, you do not need that `<intent-filter>` -- you only usually need those for activities that you are expecting other apps to start. Hence, the simplest way to get rid of this warning is to delete that `<intent-filter>` and use an explicit `Intent` when you start that activity (e.g., `new Intent(this, StartingPoint.class)`).

If you elect to keep the `<intent-filter>`, for whatever reason, please:

1. Do not use `android.intent.action.` as the prefix for your own invented actions -- come up with something else, such as `com.example.learn.tam.`
2. Add `android:exported="false"` to the `<activity>` element to say that, despite the fact that you have an `<intent-filter>`, you are not expecting other applications to start your activity